Knight, Knaves and Jokers with Layers (part 2)
So, you escaped the second room. Spoiler for linked-to Q&A:

 Your logical trickery has reduced knaves to knights, turning the majority of the room into truth-tellers. The overlords are not pleased, and you know find yourself in a room with a more even distribution of truth-tellers and jokers...

In front of you is a knight (always telling the truth), a knave (always lying) and two jokers (always answering yes or no randomly). We call these four gentlemen "quartet $A$", and you don't know who is who.
Behind them are $\displaystyle\binom{3+4-1}{4} = 15$ quartets, labelled $B_1$ to $B_{15}$. Each quartet is a set of knights, knaves and jokers, where the full set of quartets is the set of all combinations of knights, knaves and jokers, allowing for repetitions.
Behind the 15 quartets are two doors: door 1 and 2. One leads to freedom, and one to death, but you don't know which. Your goal is to guarantee your escape by asking yes-or-no questions to the knights, knaves and jokers, to which they will answer either yes or no. However, there are some rules:

You can only direct a question to a single knight/knave/joker at a time.
You cannot ask a member of quartet $A$ any questions regarding the doors.
Once you ask a question of a member of a quartet $B_i$, you cannot pose a question to a member of any other quartet.
Paradoxical questions, or questions about the future, will not be answered by anyone; joker, knight or knave.

Give a solution using the smallest maximum number of questions, and prove that it is indeed such a solution.
The next room...

Attribution: Me

It is me again. :-)

 Although it becomes harder to guarantee the escape, it is still possible.


 Below is given a solution with at most $21$ questions.


 We use the ideas from my previous answers to look for freedom. Given a statement $s$, here we proposed the logical equivalence question form $\hat s$ such that both a knight and a knave answers "yes" to $\hat s?$ iff $s$ is true. This trick allows us to replace all knaves by knights. That is, for the sake of simplicity, from now we assume that all knaves are replaced by knights and the questions are asked in the direct form $s?$ instead of the logical equivalence form $\hat s?$.


 Let $A$ consists of $A'$, $A''$, $A'''$, and $G$. We use the first question to choose a gentleman $G'$ among $A'$, $A''$ and $A'''$ such that there is a knight among $G$ and $G'$.


 Namely, we ask $A'$: "Is $A''$ a knight?"


 If the answer is "yes" then choose $A''$, otherwise choose $A'''$.


 Given a quartet $B$ among $B_1,\dots, B_{15}$, we call it a K-quartet, if $B$ contains at least three knights.


 It is easy to see that there are six non-K-quartets.


 We use the next series of questions to detect a K-quartet.


 For this purpose for $i=1,2,\dots$ we consecutively ask $G$ whether $B_i$ is a K-quartet, and if the answer is "yes" then we also ask $G'$ the same question.


 We shall stop when we obtain both answers affirmative or one of the gentlemen gave six negative answers. If we stopped when the former happened then the last two affirmative answers detected a K-quartet and we asked at most $1+2+5+5\cdot 2=18$ questions. Suppose that we stopped when the latter happened. Let the gentlemen $G^*$ gave six negative answers and the other gentleman $G^{**}$ gave $k<6$ negative answers in the series. Then we asked at most $1+6\cdot 2+k=13+k$ questions. Then we shall continue to ask $G^{**}$ consecutively whether $B_i$ is a K-quartet and shall stop when we obtain an affirmative answer or six (including those $k$) negative answers. So in any case we shall ask at most $13+6=19$ questions. If we stopped when the former happened then the affirmative answer detected a K-quartet. If we stopped when the latter happened then any of the remaining $B_i$'s is a K-quartet.


 We use the next question to detect a knight in the K-quartet $B$.


 Let $B$ consists of $B'$, $B''$, $B'''$, and $B''''$. We ask $B'$: "Is $B''$ a knight?"


 If the answer is "yes" then $B''$ is a knight, otherwise $B'''$ is a knight.


 And we use the last question to ask the knight about the door to freedom.


 Although I failed to find a solution with less questions, I do not claim the optimality of my solution. I think that even if it is optimal then it is not an easy task to prove its optimality.


Great stuff :) I edited my puzzle to explicitly disallow certain easy solutions (that would be more optimal than yours if permitted) because I think they are too easy to be interesting (and also quite controversial), and therefore I added rule 4 to exclude them. With that done (should have been done earlier) I can begin thinking about how to prove the optimality of your solution. Like before, I am pretty sure its optimal, but proving it will be harder this time. If I (or someone else clearly) proves it, then I will accept your answer.

[rot13] Va zl cebbs bs lbhe ynfg nafjre, na vzcbegnag cneg jnf fubjvat juvpu fgengrtl bs frnepuvat sbe n xavtug nzbat gur O_v unq gur fznyyrfg znkvzhz ahzore bs dhrfgvbaf. Guvf cneg jnf engure nq ubp naq vasbezny; sbe guvf cebbs, V guvax bar bhtug gb perngr n zngurzngvpny sbezhyn gung gnxrf zvavzhz ahzore bs xavtugf va gur fbhtug-nsgre gevcyrg, naq bhgchgf gur znkvzhz ahzore bs dhrfgvbaf gb ybpngr fhpu n gevcyrg cyhf gur znkvzhz ahzore bs dhrfgvbaf gb ybpngr n xavtug jvguva gung gevcyrg.

Is Alex Ravsky's answer of

 at most 21 questions

optimal? My proof of his previous answer was of a level of informality not fit for this considerably more complicated puzzle. However, the method of this proof is so that it gives a lot of insight; so if you want the most difficulty solving the next puzzle, DO NOT READ THIS PROOF YET. Alright, let us begin:

 Firstly, we reiterate the equivalence of knights and knaves using the equivalence form of a question, and herefrom simply refer to knights and knaves as knights.


 Lemma 0: We must pose our first question(s) to a member of quartet $A$.


 Proof: Rather trivial and an identical step was feautured in the linked-to proof of the previous answer. A corollary of this lemma is that we cannot begin questioning of members of quartets other than $A$ before we have some way to collect info from $A$. Thusly, the following two lemmata will regard the maximum number of questions necessary to begin collecting info from $A$, and how this info collection will function.


 Lemma 1: It is impossible to have a questioning strategy guaranteeing the identification of a knight in quartet $A$.


 Proof:   We can only allow the recipients of our questions to be members of $A$ (this restriction follows from our corollary of Lemma 0). We know the members of $A$ are two knights and two jokers.


 We know that we do not receive any information from the answers of jokers, since their answers give no information about the questions, and rule 4 means a joker could possibly act indistinguishably from a knight, meaning that their answers cannot even yield any information about their identity. If one asks a question of a gentleman whose knighthood is questionable, one may think that one also gains no information. This must be false however, as neither this puzzle, nor the previous, would have been solvable if that were the case.


 Let us look at  information collection regarding knighthood, involving a group of gentelemen that contains jokers: in Alex's answer to the previous puzzle, we saw the simplest case of this where $\# J = 1$. In that answer, he asked a gentleman $A'$ if $A''$ was a knight. An answer of "yes" gives some information; namely, that if $A'$ is a knight, then $A''$ is a knight too. So we have information in the form of an implication: $(A' = K) \implies (A'' = K)$. But, we have no information about whether or not the antecedent is true or not. Do we need it, though? Well, in a triplet with two knights and one joker, then it is mathematically so that, $\neg(A' = K) \implies (A'' = K)$. Now, it is quite obvious that $$[(P \implies Q) \land (\neg P \implies Q)] \implies Q $$ So, if the answer is yes, then we know that $A''$ is a knight, despite the fact that the joker's answers give no information. To fully remove the strangeness of the irrelevancy of the joker's informationless answer, consider this: the joker's answers may be without information, but that does not matter when no information is needed from the joker. Now, if the answer is no, then we know $A'''$ is a knight, by the same kind of logic as above. So, in the case of a triplet with one joker, we can always locate a knight, as Alex demonstrated in his solution to the previous puzzle.


 So, what is the key takeaway from this? Let $S$ be some subset of $A$: when asking our final question of some chain of questions in search of a knight, we must make sure of two things:


 1. If a knight is answering, we find a gentleman in $S$ who is a knight


 2. If a joker is answering, any of the gentlemen in $S$ is a knight


 The necessity of the first is obvious, and the necessity of the latter simply follows from the fact that if the answer gives no information, then that can only be okay if no information is needed.


 If $A$ only contains exactly one joker, and you ask $A'$ if $A'' = K$, then setting $S = A - \{ A'\}$ will allow both criteria to be met. The reason is simply that there are not enough jokers for there to be any jokers in $S$ if $A'$ is a joker.


 So, if $A$ contains two jokers, and you ask $A'$ if $A'' = K$, would setting $S = A - \{A'\}$ be sufficient? Well, even if $A'$ is a joker, there will still be another joker somewhere in $A$, and thus in $S$. We require a $S_1 \subset A$ such that $S_1 - \{A'\} = S$ will contain no jokers if $A'$ is a joker. This is impossible without knowing which gentleman is one of the jokers ahead of time. As this is all in service of the endeavour of identifying a knight, and the process to find a joker would be identical, then a strategy requiring one already knew about the identity of a joker would be a strategy requiring its own completion as a step in its completion, and is thus ruled out. Therefore, it is impossible for us to have a strategy that identifies a knight.


 Lemma 2: We can identify a subset of $A$ that contains at least one knight.


 Proof: Moving our attention to the next best thing yields the above objective. Let us look at our intermediate set $S_1$, and let $S_1 = A - \{G\}$. Now we can draw the following implications: $$[(G = J_1) \land (A' = J_2)] \implies S = \{K_1,K_2\}$$ So, if we pick some random gentleman to be excluded from our search set, then the second criterium of Lemma 1 is met if $G$ is a joker. If $G$ is not a joker, then we may be unfortunate to pick a joker from our search set. However, in this case, $G$ himself would be a knight. So, in order to get some kind of value from either of the two possible scenarios of $G = J$ and $G = K$, let us define the informer set $I = \{ G, G_s\}$, where $G_s \in S$ is the gentleman whose knighthood is (directly or indirectly) proclaimed by $A'$. Now we have the important implication: $$(G \ne K) \implies (G_s = K)$$ As such, there will always be at least one gentleman in $I$ that is a knight. Given Lemma 1, and given simple logic, it is obvious that the construction of $I$ will feature in the optimal strategy to freedom; constructing an arbitrary set $X \subset A$ with three gentlemen would also guarantee a knight was among them, but this would cause one to have a much larger maximum of questions, which is pretty clear one's we see how many questions are required to deal with just one joker in $I$.


 Lemma 3: The optimal way to locate a knight among the $B_i$ is to first search for a $B_i$ with three knights and then search for a knight within that set.


 Using identical logic to my proof of Alex's answer to the previous puzzle, we have that all knight-searching strategies are categorized as such:


 0. Looking for a knight directly.


 1. Looking for a $B_i$ with at least one knight, and then looking for a knight within that $B_i$.


 2. Looking for a $B_i$ with at least two knights, and then looking for a knight within that $B_i$.


 3. Looking for a $B_i$ with at least three knight, and then looking for a knight within that $B_i$.


 4. Looking for a $B_i$ with four knights.


 Firstly, we must understand how one can question a set containing a joker that's maximally disagreeing with the knight whilst still keeping its cover  (we assume this as we have to analyze the worst case scenario in order to calculate the maximum number of questions asked). Let say we have some ordered set $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n \}$, and we ask $I$, for some values of $i$ and some predicate $P$, if $P(x_i)$ is true.


 Are we guaranteed to find a $x_i$ for which $P$ holds? No. Let $A(G,P)$ mean that the gentleman $G$ affirms the proposition $P$. Now imagine a situation where the following biconditional holds always: $$A(G,P(x_i)) \iff \neg A(G_s,P(x_i))$$ In this case, maximal disagreement within $I$ maintains ignorance forever. So, we need some kind of fact that makes it so that the joker cannot lie indefinitely without blowing their cover. Imagine if we know for a fact that $P$ holds of $a$ many $x_i$. That means that if one of the gentlemen says $P$ does not hold of $x_i$ more than $n-a$ times, then that gentleman must be a joker.


 Then the question becomes, can both gentlemen stay within this limit and still disagree on every $x_i$? That depends on the relation between $a$ and $n$. Imagine if $n-a < n/2$. That means that $G$ can say "no" exactly $n-a$ times, and $G_s$ can say "no" exactly $n-a$ times, each time on a separate occassion from $G$, and when the dust settles, there are still $x_i$ left in $X$. The reason is that since $n-a < n/2$, then $2(n-a) < n$. We have that   $P$ must hold of these, because since both gentlemen have respectively said $P$ does not hold of a distinct $x_i$ $n-a$ times, that means that a knight has said so. Thus, we know that all the $x_i$ for which $P$ does not hold are among those $2(n-a)$ $x_i$, which means $P$ holds of any of the remaining $x_i$.


 We turn $n-a < n/2$ into the condition $a > n/2$. If this condition is not met, then one cannot guarantee that questioning $I$ will identify an element with the desired property. So, imagine for argument we've identified a quartet with at least $a$ knights. So, what must $a$ be to guarantee we find a knight within that quartet? Well, $n = 4$, so $a \ge 3$. However, when we set $a = 4$, are we guaranteed to find such a quartet in the first place? Let's ask a more general question: how many $B_i$ exist with at least $x$ knights? Knights come in two varities; originally a knight and originally a knave, which is something we must take into account in our calculations. Let us ask how many quartets have exactly $x$ knights: that is the same as asking how many combinations (of length $x$) of the first and second variety we have, where we allow repetitions. As such, the number of quartets with exactly $x$ knights is this: $$\binom{2 + x - 1}x = x +1$$ Thusly, the number of quartets with at least $x$ knights is this: $$ \sum_{i=x}^4 i+1  = \binom{5+1}2 - \binom{x+1}2 = 15 - \binom{x+1}2$$ Where we set $\binom ab = 0 \iff a <b$. Setting $x = 4$, we see we have $5$ such $B_i$, and $5 \not > 15/2$. Therefore, if we are looking for quartets first, they must be quartets containing at least $3$ knights. What if we are just for knights; that is, the zeroth possibility? Well, the number of knights among the $15\cdot 4 = 60$ gentlemen can be calculated as this: $$\begin{align} \# K \ \text{in total} &= \sum_{x=1}^4 | \{ B_i \mid \# K = x \}| \cdot x \\[2ex] &= \sum_{x=1}^4 (x+1)x \\[2ex] &= 2\sum_{x=1}^4 \frac{(x+1)x}2  \\[2ex] &= 2\sum_{x=1}^4 \binom{x+1}2 \\[2ex] &= 2\binom{4+2}3 \\[2ex] &= 40   \end{align} $$ Now, $40 > 60/2$, so just searching for knights directly is definitely a possibility. But is it optimal?


 Alex's answer showed that the maximum number of questions used to inquire about a knight in the $B_i$, using his strategy of first searching for a $B_i$ with at least three knights, was $19$. To confirm this, we must confirm the optimality of the question algorithm used.


 Let the property that we are trying to affirm of some element be denoted $P()$, and let the act of affirmation be again denoted as $A()$. Alex's algorithm, when no gentleman has said "no" $n-a$ times, works like this: $$A(G, P(x_i)) \mapsto \text{ask}(G_s,P(x_i))$$ $$\neg A(G, P(x_i)) \mapsto \text{ask}(G,P(x_{i+1}))$$ This runs up until a gentleman has said "no" $n-a$ times, or until both gentlemen affirm $P(x_i)$. To see that this algorithm is optimal, observe simply that one could potentially waste questions if either of these rules were not imposed. When $G$ affirms $P(x_i)$, then the principle of maximal disagreement requires $G_s$ to deny it; but if one does not ask $G_s$ about $P(x_i)$, then one does not gain another "no" from $G_s$, bringing oneself no closer to the end, all at the expense of a question. As such, the question posed to $G$ would be a waste.


 Let us see why the second rule is optimal. If one were to ask $G_s$ about $P(x_i)$, then a "no" would be informationally valuable then just as it would at any other point, making the question valuable. But if $G_s$ answered "yes", that would make the question a waste. If one did not have this rule, one would drive up the maximum number of questions.


 Now, the algorithm as described here is not yet complete, as it only tells one what to do up until a gentleman has said "no" $n-a$ times. What happens once one has reached that point? Well, then the algorithm takes this form: $$A(G_s,P(x_i)) \mapsto \text{program finished}$$ $$\neg A(G_s, P(x_i)) \mapsto \text{ask}(G_s,P(x_{i+1}))$$ This will continue until $G_s$ total number of denials is equal to $n-a$, after which the program is finished and the questioner could pick any $x_i$ with $i$ greater than any of the $i$-values that featured in the program. Why is this correct, and if correct, why is it optimal? Well, let us look at the correctness of the first rule. If $G$ is a knight, then after he has said "no" $n-a$ times, then any $x_i$ from then on will be one of the elements for which $P$ holds. If $G$ is a joker, then $G_s$ is a knight, which means him affirming $P(x_i)$ means that $P$ truly does hold of $x_i$. So, this rule is correct, and the second rule is definitely correct in the sense that it will not cause one to affirm $P$ of an $x_i$ for which it does not hold.


 The reason it is optimal is because its alternatives are trivially suboptimal; the alternatives would all involve asking $G$ something, but there is nothing more $G$ can tell us. If $G$ says "no", he would prove he is the joker (by saying "no" more than $n-a$ times), which he would not do in the case where one asks the maximum number of questions. If $G$ says "yes", then confirming this would require asking $G_s$ as well, which means we can just restrict our questioning to $G_s$ only (and thus, for optimality's sake, we must restrict our questioning to $G_s$ only at this point).


 Now that we've proven the optimality of the algorithm, we can finally answer the question of whether Alex's search strategy is better than just searching for a knight directly (the aforementioned zeroth possibility). However, seeing this is trivial, given that the number of steps (and thus questions) of the algorithm depends on $n-a$. In Alex's case, $n-a = 15 - 9 = 6$ for his search for a quartet with at least three knights; then, for his search for a knight within that quartet, he needs only one question. In the alternative, we have that $n-a = 60 - 40 = 20$, which will clearly have a higher maximum number of questions. Thus, we've proven the optimality of Alex's knight-searching strategy.


 Lemma 4: The total number of questions asked is at most $21$


 Proof: Alex needed one question to construct the informer set $I$. He needed (as proven in his answer) at most $19$ questions to find a knight among the $B_i$. He needs to ask that knight the question about which doors leads to freedom in order to escape, which is the last question. Thus we have a total of $1 + 19 + 1 = 21$ questions. That however, proves that Alex's solution of at most $21$ questions is optimal.


Phew, that was a behemoth. Feel free to point out any typos or errata, as I am a bit cooked after writing all that and may have missed some stuff.

Does this assume that if you want to find a group with 3 knights, then you can only ask questions of the form "does this group have 3 knights?"

@noedne It does not assume any kind of form of the question directly, but rather assumes the result of a question: if the answer is "no", then that means the gentleman claims there are less than $3$ knights in that quartet; if the answer is "yes", then that means the gentleman claims there are at least $3$ knights in that quartet.

But aren't there other reasonable questioning strategies that would have to be considered, such as asking questions of the form "does one of these two groups have 3 knights?" or "do two of these three groups have 3 knights?" etc.?

@noedne [1/2] Definitely, and that was just something I forgot to consider. I think perhaps a separate answer can be posted dealing with exactly this, an answer which my proof can refer to within the appropriate section. It is however possible that such a proof would prove Alex's solution is not optimal. That would be quite exciting, and I do think it has the potential for that. However, only one of your examples are reasonable. "Does one of these two groups have $3$ knights" does not allow for a guarantee that you find a 3-knight quartet or a knight directly.

@noedne [2/2] The reason is that you maybe only have one 3-knight quartet out of two quartets, which means $a \not > n/2$, and you maybe only have $3$ knights out of $8$ gentlemen, which means $a \not > n/2$. Therefore, in both cases, you cannot guarantee finding a knight. Your second example however, is as far as I know, possible. I will investigate this possibility a little, though a full investigation will require a considerable amount of math, which means if I am the one to add this revision to my proof, it may be in a little while, since I'll need the time to sit down with it properly.

To elaborate, I think one possible search strategy is to ask "Does one of these two groups have 3 knights?", and if you get yeses, ask "Does this group have 3 knights?" for one of the two groups. This probably requires the same maximum number of questions in the worst case, but there are also other search strategies like this to consider.

@noedne Divide the 15 quartets into 5 triplets of quartets. There are 9 of the desired quartets; one can distribute them as such: $(D_1,D_2, D_3), \ (D_4, D_5, D_6), \ (D_7, X, X), \ (D_8, X, X), \ (D_9, X, X)$. If $P$ is the property of a triplet containing at  least $2$ desirable quartets, then we see there is a case where $a$, the number of triplets for which $P$ holds, does not satisfy $a > n/2$, which is necessary to guarantee finding such a triplet of quartets. So, I believe I've ruled out that particular example too, but the general case is yet to be shown.

@noedne ""Does one of these two groups have 3 knights?" As I showed in my comment (building on the math of my proof), this questioning does not allow for guaranteeing that one finds a knight, because of the fact that $a \not > n/2$. If that formula makes no sense, just revisit my answer. I do agree with you fully that the idea of searching for groups first, and then quartets within those groups, could as far as we know, yield better solutions, and therefore any proof of Alex' solution must rule them out. It would be interesting if Alex' streak of optimal solutions would be broken bc of this.

I don't see how a <= n/2 applies here. If there exists a group that everyone agrees has 3 knights, then asking "Does one of these two groups have 3 knights?" will get a yes from everyone if one of those two is the desired one. Then you pick one of the two and ask "Does this group have 3 knights?" If everyone says yes, you've found the desired group. Otherwise, the other group is the desired one. What am I missing here?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
